# How do I add images to my PHP blog?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have made a blog for my website with PHP and mysql database, where I can add blog posts from an admin site (www.website.com/admin) and display them on my website (www.website.com). It's working fine, **but I want to add pictures too**.

This is my code for adding:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $blogtitle = htmlentities($_POST['blogtitle'], ENT_QUOTES);
    $blogdate = htmlentities($_POST['blogdate'], ENT_QUOTES);
    $blogdesc = htmlentities($_POST['blogdesc'], ENT_QUOTES);

// check that firstname and lastname are both not empty
if ($blogtitle == '' || $blogdesc == '') {

    $error = 'Please fill in all required fields';
    renderForm($blogtitle, $blogdesc, $error);

} else {

// insert the new record into the database
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT blog_posts (blogtitle, blogdate, blogdesc) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $blogtitle, $blogdate, $blogdesc);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    echo "ERROR: Could not prepare SQL statement.";
}
    header("Location: website.php");
}

} else {
renderForm();
}
}

// close the mysqli connection
$mysqli->close();
```

And my code for display the blog posts

```
/.../
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {

    echo "<div>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->blogtitle . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->blogdate . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->blogdesc . "</td>";
    echo "</div>";
 }
```

I know how to make an upload.php, but is it easier to upload to mysql? I dont know how to get the image shown in the right blogpost after uploading.

Best regards,
Tobias Dybdahl

Comment: Typically blogs will allow the description to include HTML, Markup or something similar that will allow you to put images in the text. A WYSIWYG editor (such as CKEditor or TinyMCE) will make this easy. As for uploading the images, look at a file manager. There are plenty of free ones to use if you Google for them.

Comment: using WYSIWYG editor is not good if he want to use the image again an other article

Comment: You are receiving a lot of downvotes because this question has way too many solutions.  You are basically asking us to do your work for you.  Consider simply adding another column to the database called ImageURL that points to an image online, then reference that URL in an `<img />` tag in another `td` tag in your output then work from there.  Once you have an idea of how you are going to _display_ the images, then worry about how to upload them.  Lastly, there's already a ton of resources online for how to store/retrieve images in MySql and display them in PHP, I would Google that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload the file to the server and then store the filename in your database, for example a column named "blogimg".

Then in your code for displaying blog posts you can add this line to show the image:

```
echo "<td><img src='" . $row->blogimg . "' /></td>";
```

Comment: How do i store the URL name in the database on upload?

Comment: If you do this when submitting the form you can add this to your insert statement. If you do it at an other place you can use an update statement

Answer (score 0):

you need to upload images to a directory and save images name in a database
after that right the url of the image in img tag and get the image name from the database

your html form

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

your php code

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
?>
```